# What is the equivalence of Meteksan MILDAR in US inventory?

Tags: radar

This is called MILDAR radar.

[image]

This is manufactured by a Turkish company named Meteksan.

Is this Turkish equivalent of [Longbow radar](http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/LONGBOWFireControlRadar/Pages/default.aspx)?

If yes, why is that radar pylon-mounted rather than mast-mounted?

Comment: Yes, the Millimetre Wave Radar (MILDAR) mounted on the T-129 ATAK helicopter is similar to the Longbow Fire Control Radar that features on the US  Apache helicopters. http://www.northropgrumman.com/Capabilities/LONGBOWFireControlRadar/Documents/longbow.pdf  The radar is pylon mounted because the helicopter is not using the pylon to carry any weapons(rockets/missiles).As/when it does the radar will be mounted on the mast.

Comment: This would be better answered on a site focusing on weaponry, but intuitively, if this is a radar made to scan and select targets on the ground at very short distance, it should be more efficient when fixed at the lowest possible location, and if the weight is really too important (balance), then the mast is the last resort solution.

Comment: @mins, then, why doesn't apache mount any radar on pylons?